# Does there any way that can make the autofill come out in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Does anyone know how to let the autofill thing come out whenever I want?

[image: Autofill thing]

It is really frustrating that I have to retype my code so that the autofill thing will automatically come out, currently that is my way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by myself. It is `control + space` and the **Basic code completion** will come out.

Also can use `Control+Shift+Space` and **Smart code completion** (filters the list of methods and variables by expected type) will come out

[Check out other shortcut here!](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts)